# MYSQL/Laravel Migrations Change composite key to autoincrement

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a pivot table (exercise_task) with two rows. At the moment the two rows build a composite primary key.
Unfortunately it turned out that this was a terrible idea since now I need to be able to add the same task several times to an exercise.

Therefore I either need to switch to an auto incrementing primary key.

Besides I need to add an index row (which indicates the order) so it would also be possible to extend the composite key.

**Question**
What's the best way to achieve this? Since the database is already in use i can't just delete the table.

**Original Migration**

```
Schema::create('exercise_task', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('exercise_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('exercise_id')->references('id')->on('exercises')
        ->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')
            ->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        $table->primary(['exercise_id', 'task_id']);
    });
```

Comment: Why not refactor your code and migrate the data to a new table with an auto icremental key ..

Comment: Please post your migration.

Comment: Here is my original migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following:
1. Drop all foreign keys of the pivot table **(This was the key)**
2. Drop Primary Key
3. Add new Primary Key (I decided to extend the composite key by the new index column)
4. Readd the previously dropped foreign keys.

Comment: Sure I just forgot it because of the "you have to wait for x days until you can flag your own answer as correct" thing. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I recommend either refactoring your code to fix this from scratch, or use the following code in a MySQL Terminal window to add an index row:

`INSERT INTO name 
VALUES ('column1 value', 'column2 value', 'column3 value', 'column4 value');`